# Horses.. The right way??

Tags: sfx, horse

What's the best fastest way to cut them? I know they have a few different styles of running and it can be very rhythmic but I tried hitting it like foley and spot every step but it doesn't feel right, the only thing that really is working for me is layering a couple tracks for the fast running, obviously the walking and what not is easier to cut but what I'm doing sounds good I'm just not sure if I'm doin it right or I'm being too lazy?

Thanks!! You guys rock

Answer (score 4):

The important thing is if it sounds good, and feels good you're probably on the right track.  In the past I've had luck finding the style that's close to the rhythm and pace of the picture, even if it's not perfect.  You can then time compress or expand (within reason of course) to match the picture.  One tip I learned from a friend is, if you're having trouble transitioning from a gallop to a canter or walk, add a horse vocal (A whiny, snort or breath) at the transition.  It helps draw attention away from the feet.  Granted I always try and make it work first, but sometimes (especially in television when time is limited) you need to pick your battles.

Comment: If using Pro Tools, elastic audio is perfect for those little tweaks!

Answer (score 1):

@sonicdesigns

I found this helpful watching Gary Hecker do this.  Your question made me think of this.  He this helps.